# How to use inline fragments in GraphQL query thanks to ApiPlatform project and Doctrine Inheritance?

Tags: php, graphql, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com, graphql-php

Thank you by advance for your help !
Before detailing my need, let me introduce the context :

### Project stack:

| tech/lib | version |
| --- | --- |
| **php** | 8.1 |
| **symfony** | v6.1 |
| **api-platform** | v2.6 |
| **webonyx/graphql-php** | v14.11 |

### Doctrine model/entities

To simplify the example, I've used the example found in this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/interfaces-and-unions.html).

[image]

My Event class is abstract :

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: "event")]
#[ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")]
#[ApiResource]
abstract class Event
{
//...

}
```

The others (Concert, Festival and Conference) are extending it :

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
class Concert extends Event
{
//...

}
```

and so on for the others.

### My goal

I want to use [inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments) to get in a single query my concrete events :

```
query {
  events {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        minAgeRestriction
        startsAt

        ... on Festival {
          performers
        }

        ... on Concert {
          performingBand
        }

        ... on Conference {
          speakers
          workshops
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### The error I get

> Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "Event" can never be of type "Concert".

How to tell GraphqlPhp through ApiPlatform to generate union type ?
Did I missed something ? Is it not possible yet with api-platform ?

I'm not expert at all on GraphQL but I don't see anything about inline fragment in api-platform while graphql-php looks to support it w: https://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/type-definitions/unions/

Could be related : https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/2105
What do you think ? Any clue ?

Comment: Is the `event` type a `union` of `Festival`, `Concert` and `Conference`?

Comment: I guess not but actually, I don't know how tell to ApiPlatform / graphql-php to generate such union type. The only thing I do now is to make the `Festival`, `Concert` and `Conference` extend the abstract `Event`. I've tried to add some phpdoc but it didn't works...